# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'preventDefault' While attempting to intercept navigation using Kendo UI Router

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm trying to intercept all navigation using a Kendo UI router.

This is my router initialization and my document ready function:

```
$(function () {
    router.start();
    $("#button").kendoButton();
    alert("document is ready.");
});

var router = new kendo.Router();

router.bind("change", function (e) {
    console.log("change event: ", e.url);
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I get the Uncaught TypeError when I first navigate to the page, but when I provide a different hash fragment such as `/#/foo` the router works as expected and prevents the default behaviour.

I tried:

```
if(e.url != "/"){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

But that just moves the problem to my other initializations, (e.g. The `$("#button").kendoButton();` in my document ready function now produces the same Uncaught TypeError.

I've included the appropriate libraries in my .cshtml like so:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in kendoRouter's `start` or `_urlChanged` method (and/or the documentation) to me. Try calling `router.start()` before binding the change event:

```
$(function () {
    $("#button").kendoButton();
    alert("document is ready.");
});

var router = new kendo.Router();
router.start();

router.bind("change", function (e) {
    console.log("change event: ", e.url);
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: I updated to the Q3 version of Kendo UI for ASP.NET and the error no longer propagates to the button initialization. It is however still present when I navigate to the default route. I will try what you said and let you know. Thank you.